# Cannot run refind-install from Recovery because "/usr/bin/env: bad interpreter"

Tags: macos, command-line, error, path, efi

I have managed to change the present working directory to the folder containing downloaded rEFInd files. I have booted to Recovery Mode. The `refind-bin-0.11.3` folder was downloaded to my `Downloads` folder.

I came across a new problem: ‘bad interpreter: no such file or directory’.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I've edited the question down to just the latest unresolved problem. Feel free to expand further to add some context.

Comment: the users messenge**rm**? Lol. That could lead to some mistakes if a space is misplaced.

Comment: Yes, Messengerm, it doesn't have underscore between, thought I could add a space between the two, but couldn't. but making changes in the user name can happen. but can't get Mac OS X to keep the user name in high caps. so yeah.....no mistake in username. Mac OS X will not allow to have space between "messenger" and "m" but yeah, we all choose names and who we want to be......

Comment: but other than that Jbis......this is the problem I came across in terminal........ env is missing and I got the error message -bash: ./refind-install: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory. this terminal is from recovery mode partition.

Comment: @Jbis  A space being misplaced? I don't see where....I can see error message so maybe it's caused by some mistakes. but we need to be very serious. plus I tried two command line paths in recovery partition, one was . refind-install and other was source refind-install, both lead me to an BSing error message telling me refind binary file is missing(it's talking about refine-bin-0.11.3 file being missing)...

Comment: @M3553N63R Your message makes no sense. Whats the problem?

Comment: @Jbis  so let me explain this to you, I first typed cd "/volumes/Macintosh hd/users/messengerm/downloads/refind-bin-0.11.3  2ndly I hit enter, 3rdly I typed ls then 4thly got the pleasant good sign I was in the right directory showing the script items in Refind-bin-0.11.3 file confirming(verifying the file exists and I was in the directory to Refind-bin-0.11.3 file) then I typed ./refind-install as instructed, got error message as shown above in screen shot. then got an answer response from GRG and a comment response from fd0....so I clicked link https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/331985/37797

Comment: Run this `bash ./refind-install`

Comment: @Jbis getting to the part....to explain what the problem is. ......

Comment: I did run that script as shown in screen shot. Refind-bin-0.11.3 file is not missing because I can clearly see the file. I'm not sure if the file shows as blue folder on your Mac but for me it does on mine, and it's in downloads. so the computer tells me and shows me it's there but in error message after trying source refind-install, and other scripted command line . refind-install, <---- that one without the slash. however in recovery partition in terminal I will type Bash ./refind-install and see what happens....

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the ‘refind-install’ script has a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) pointing to `/usr/bin/env`, such as

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

The Recovery environment doesn't have a `/usr/bin/env`, so attempting to access that path returns the error that there's ‘no such file or directory’ there.

You can manually choose a shell to execute a script with by passing the script to the shell:

```
bash ./refind-install
```

Alternatively, you should be able to edit the script to point directly at the shell. Replace the first line in the script with something like this, presuming the line above is what's in the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Note the space has been removed.

[I have `/usr/bin/env` in my "Macintosh HD" but not in the recovery partition. Is this normal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/331985/37797)

Comment: If you're talking about the rEFInd-Install script, How do I edit the script? mind giving the walk through? much appreciated.

Comment: @M3553N63R See edited answer for running a script with a shell of your choice without editing the shebang by JBis

Comment: You don't want to run a script in "any" shell because each shell has its own syntax. While `ksh`,`zsh`, and `bash` use `bourne` like syntax that is the same in each shell, they also have syntax that is unique to each shell. Best practice would be to read the first line ( the shebang)- `head -n1 refind-install` then use  that shell within the shebang.

Comment: tried Bash ./refind-install then like always I get told "copying sample configuration file as refind.conf; edit this file to configure rEFInd.

Comment: @David Anderson Can we speak in chat room?